# Выборка данных из бд

Tags: php, база-данных

```
mysql_select_db("b7_13470696_dd",$conn);

$rezult=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM lesson1 WHERE id<200 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1',$conn);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($rezult);
echo "$row[textRUS]"
```

как сделать так, чтобы не рандомно выводило, а по очереди.

Comment: А вы хотите чтоб вывило одну запись или все?

Comment: Мне кажется что проще можно решить твою задачу...без таких извращений..опиши в чем именно задача как и что у тебя выводиться из скрипта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['my_record_id'])) 
{
  $current_record=(int)$_COOKIE['my_record_id'];
  setcookie('my_record_id',($current_record+1),time()+3600);
}else
{
  $current_record=1;
  setcookie('my_record_id',($current_record+1),time()+3600);
};
mysql_select_db("b7_13470696_dd",$conn);
$rezult=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM lesson1 WHERE id='.$current_record.';',$conn);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($rezult); 
echo "$row[textRUS]";
```

В теории должно работать.

Comment: если будут пропуски id, будет работать, но не всегда...  
в куки надо писать выбранный id, а выбирать следующий по порядку, т.е. `id>$current_record order by id limit 1`

Comment: Согласен) тогда сразу еще допилить  

    where id>=IF(max(id)<$current_record,max(id),id>$current_record) order by id limit 1;

и при достижении последней записи будет всегда последняя выводится.

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY id DESC` или `ASC`

Comment: при обновлении страницы, не меняются данные из бд

Comment: по одной записи, обновил страницу, вывело из бд одну запись, обновил еще раз, следующую запись, как рандом, только по очереди, чтобы выводилось